# I cannot get data values from the web table

Tags: python, tkinter, statistics

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen
from tkinter import *

def statno():
    covidTk = Tk()
    covidTk.title('Data statistics of COVID-19')
    
    lb1 = Label(covidTk,text='Country: ')
    lb1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

    lb2 = Label(covidTk,text=entcon.get())
    lb2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

    driverPath = 'D:\geckodriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driverPath)
    url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries'
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
    browser.get(url)

    table = browser.find_elements_by_id("main_table_countries_today")
    columns = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//thead/tr')
    rows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr')
    for column in columns:
        for row in rows:
            df = pd.DataFrame({column:{row}})
    
    lb3 = Label(covidTk,text='No of cases: ')
    lb3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

    death_cases = str(df.values['Total Cases'][lb2.cget('text')])
    lb4 = Label(covidTk,text=death_cases)
    lb4.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
    
    
    
    

win = Tk()
win.title('COVID-19 tracker')

web = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus')
objSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(web.text,'lxml')

lbtitle = Label(win,text='Covid-19 Statistics')
lbtitle.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

lbcon = Label(win,text='Country: ')
lbcon.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=20)

conname = StringVar()
entcon = Entry(win,textvariable=conname)
entcon.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=20)

btncheck = Button(win,text='Check data',command=statno)
btncheck.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lbcase = Label(win,text='Coronavirus Cases: ')
lbcase.grid(row=3,column=0)

total = objSoup.find_all('div',{'class':'maincounter-number'})
total_cases = total[0]
lbdat1 = Label(win,text=total_cases.text)
lbdat1.grid(row=3,column=1)

lbdeaths = Label(win,text='Deaths: ')
lbdeaths.grid(row=4,column=0)

total_deaths = total[1]
lbdat2 = Label(win,text=total_deaths.text)
lbdat2.grid(row=4,column=1)

lbcase = Label(win,text='Recovered: ')
lbcase.grid(row=5,column=0)

total_recover = total[2]
lbdat3 = Label(win,text=total_recover.text)
lbdat3.grid(row=5,column=1)


Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python Projects Fun\covid_gui.py", line 34, in statno
    death_cases = str(df.values['Total Cases'][lb2.cget('text')])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or 
boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Sorry I may want to extract the value in the corresponding column and row and put the value as label in tkinter but however I got the above error because the table includes commas between numbers so what should I convert them in order to get the value? Because I do not know how to deal with the commas in the corresponding value

Comment: I think you need to convert `lb2.cget('text')` to integer in order to use it as index as the error said.

Comment: Like ```int(lb2.cget('text'))``` right?

Comment: Yes if it is a valid integer string.

Comment: Sorry but lb2 is the country name

Comment: My aim is to get the table value

Comment: Then I think you need `df['Total Cases'][lb2.cget('text')]` instead.

Comment: What should I write?

Comment: Change the error line to that.

Comment: I got the key error after changing and mentioned that key error: Total Cases but the column name is 'Total Cases'

Comment: I think you better print out the data of `df` to see whether it is what you expect.

Comment: It has unlimited data so do I need to refer the table that I need?

Comment: I do not know how to indicate the column and row and value of the table

Comment: Try `df.at[lb2.cget('text'), 'Total Cases']`.

Comment: I changed my script and post on the new question

Comment: There is an error ```At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers``` so what can I change ?

Comment: Can you clarify what the line `death_cases = str(df.values['Total Cases'][lb2.cget('text')])` want to get? The number of cases for a particular country? If yes, try `df = df.set_index('Country')` and then `death_cases = str(df.at[lb2.cget('text'), 'Total Cases'])`.